# See Nth previous version of file

Tags: git

I would like to see an older version of a file, but this:

```
git show HEAD~1:main.c
```

gives me the previous commit. That file has not changed since the previous commit, so I see the same content. In order to find an older version of that file, I need to start increasing manually the revision spec until I find an actual difference. This is frustrating.

In this particular case, I do not care about commits: I just want to see previous versions of this specific file. How can I give a revision specification of  the type "the Nth oldest version"? The revision specifications [I know](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) are always commit-related, not file-version related.

The closest I have got is:

```
git log --follow --pretty=oneline -- annotated-bower.json
```

Which gives me a list of the commits where this file has been changed. Now that I see this list, how can I tell `git show` something like:

```
git show OLDER~3:main.c
```

Without having to manually copy-paste the commit spec:

```
git show b27a57c6732200d8ef8b5b8c87d07fe67f37e9db:main.c
```

I can of course implement this myself:

```
git-previous.sh main.c 3
```

Parsing the output of `git log --follow --pretty=oneline` to get the commit hash and call then `git show` with that, but I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel. Besides, this seems like a so useful feature, that this is *surely* part of stock `git`, and I have just overseen it, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you don't have to parse anything if you feed `git log` correctly:

```
git log -10 --follow --pretty=%h -- /path/to/your/file
```

prints out the last 10 (`-10`) short commit hashes (`%h`) for your file.

Take the output of `git log`, put it into a list and loop over the entries. Done.

Perhaps this is the reason why there's no separate command to achieve this... And regarding your note about

> Besides, this seems like a so useful feature [...]

I'm using git since a good while now and never actually had the need for viewing the history of a file in a sequence. Changes are interesting. Therefore, you could also feed a path to `gitk` which will result in a list of changes displayed with their differences in `gitk`:

```
gitk -- /path/to/your/file
```

Comment: "Take the output of git log, put it into a list and loop over the entries. Done." I do not call that *done*, as in, I am quickly going to see the 5th version of that file. That takes a lot of typing (and typos), so I will have to put that into a script if git does not support that out of the box. And we are probably using git differently, because I need this kind of workflow sometimes (albeit not very often)

Comment: And yes, gitk is doing the right thing here, but I want a command-line version of that (which seems git does not offer, out-of-the-box?)

Comment: Accepting this. It seems git can not do this directly, so some scripting is needed.